# Filter AngularJS REST JSON Data: error:badcfg Response does not match configured parameter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest

I am trying to use a routeparam to filter the results from a REST call, but am not getting any results returned but rather receiving the following error:

```
Error: error:badcfg Response does not match configured parameter
Error in resource configuration for action `get`. Expected response to contain an object but got an array
```

The value I am attempting to get is by the articlecategoryid. If I drop my URL into a browser tool such as Postman it works. An example URL that returns as desired by articlecategoryid is as follows:

```
https://myrestcall.net/tables/articles/?$filter=(articlecategoryid eq 1)
```

However, using this in Angular does not seem to resolve and produces the error.

Here is some sample REST Data from this call:

```
[
{
    "id": "66D5069C-DC67-46FC-8A51-1F15A94216D4",
    "articletitle": "artilce1",
    "articlecategoryid": 1,
    "articlesummary": "article 1 summary. "
},
   {
    "id": "66D5069C-DC67-46FC-8A51-1F15A94216D5",
    "articletitle": "artilce2",
    "articlecategoryid": 1,
    "articlesummary": "article 2 summary. "
}, 
{
    "id": "66D5069C-DC67-46FC-8A51-1F15A94216D6",
    "articletitle": "artilce3",
    "articlecategoryid": 1,
    "articlesummary": "article 3 summary. "
},   
]
```

Here is my App setup:

```
var pfcModule = angular.module('pfcModule', [
'ngRoute',
'ui.bootstrap',
'auth0',
'angular-storage',
'angular-jwt',
'pfcServices',
'pfcControllers']);

pfcModule.config([
'$routeProvider',
'authProvider',
'$httpProvider',
'$locationProvider',
'jwtInterceptorProvider',
function ($routeProvider, authProvider, $httpProvider, $locationProvider, jwtInterceptorProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
        when('/home', { templateUrl: './views/home.html' }).
        when('/categories/:articlecategoryID', { templateUrl: './views/categories.html', controller: 'pfcCategoriesCtrl' }).
        when('/article/:articleID/:articleTitle', { templateUrl: './views/article.html', controller: 'pfcCtrl2' }).
        when('/add-article', { templateUrl: './views/add-article.html', controller: 'pfcPost', requiresLogin: true }).
        when('/login', { templateUrl: './views/login.html', controller: 'loginCtrl' }).
        otherwise({ redirectTo: '/home' });
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-ZUMO-APPLICATION'] = 'myid';
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Content-Type'] = 'Application/json';
    authProvider.init({
        domain: 'mydomain',
        clientID: 'myid',
        callbackURL: location.href,
        loginUrl: '/login'
    });

    jwtInterceptorProvider.tokenGetter = function (store) {
        return store.get('token');
    }

    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('jwtInterceptor');
}])

.run(function ($rootScope, auth, store, jwtHelper, $location) {
$rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function () {
    if (!auth.isAuthenticated) {
        var token = store.get('token');
        if (token) {
            if (!jwtHelper.isTokenExpired(token)) {
                auth.authenticate(store.get('profile'), token);
            } else {
                $location.path('/login');
            }
        }
    }

});
});
```

Here is my service:

```
     var pfcServices = angular.module('pfcServices', ['ngResource'])


pfcServices.factory('pfcArticleCategories', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('https://myrestcall.net/tables/articles/?$filter=(articlecategoryid eq :articlecategoryID)', { articlecategoryID: '@articlecategoryid' },
    {
        'update': { method: 'PATCH' }
    }
    );
}]);
```

Here is my controller:

```
 var pfcControllers = angular.module('pfcControllers', ['auth0']);

pfcControllers.controller('pfcCategoriesCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', 'pfcArticleCategories', function ($scope, $routeParams, pfcArticleCategories) {
    $scope.category = pfcArticleCategories.get({ articlecategoryID: $routeParams.articlecategoryID });
}]);
```

Here is the page that would output the REST data (categories.html):

```
div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4">
    <h2>Heading</h2>
    Sort By: <select ng-model="articleSortOrder">
        <option value="+id">ID</option>
        <option value="+articletitle">Article Title</option>
        <option value="+articlecategoryid">Article Category</option>
    </select>
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Category ID</th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="articles in category | orderBy:articleSortOrder">
            <td>{{articles.id}}</td>
            <td>{{articles.articletitle}}</td>
            <td>{{articles.articlecategoryid}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Here is how I link into this page to filter it by the routeparam (home.html):

```
<a href="#categories/1">Article 1 Category</a>
<a href="#categories/2">Article 2 Category</a>
```

**UPDATE:** My other REST calls are working, even with a routeparam such as https://myrestcall.net/tables/articles/:articleID so I am focusing on the ?$filter= aspect of the failing call. Have others had issues with passing values into a REST call, as the variable is not directly after a / as it is in /:articleID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it! The issue is in the controller as I was using a 'Get'. A 'Get' works fine for retrieving something by the id (ex. https://myrestcall.net/tables/articles/:articleID).

However, I needed to use the 'query' command as this has an implicit isArray:true (please see the [Angular Resource Doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource#!) where it states 'query':  {method:'GET', isArray:true},)

When I changed my controller from:

```
 pfcControllers.controller('pfcCategoriesCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', 'pfcArticleCategories', function ($scope, $routeParams, pfcArticleCategories) {
$scope.category = pfcArticleCategories.get({ articlecategoryID: $routeParams.articlecategoryID });
}]);
```

To:

```
pfcControllers.controller('pfcCategoriesCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', 'pfcArticleCategories', function ($scope, $routeParams, pfcArticleCategories) {
$scope.category = pfcArticleCategories.query({ articlecategoryID: $routeParams.articlecategoryID });
}]);
```

It resolves as desired.

Answer (score 1):

In your `pfcServices` factory definition add `isArray:true` to         `'update': { method: 'PATCH' }`, every time you get a JSON array as a result you need to add `isArray: true` to method definition.

```
  var pfcServices = angular.module('pfcServices', ['ngResource'])
pfcServices.factory('pfcArticleCategories', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
        return $resource('https://myrestcall.net/tables/articles/?$filter=(articlecategoryid eq :articlecategoryID)', { articlecategoryID: '@articlecategoryid' },
        {
            'update': { method: 'PATCH', isArray:true }
        }
        );
    }]);
```

`isArray` – {boolean=} – If true then the returned object for this action is an array, see returns section.

See docs [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource#usage)

Comment: Does this include a "Get" action, as I only defined a method for the update but am only using a "Get" at this time

Comment: I added the isArray: true, but it still gives me the error. When I hardcode the REST call to ?$filter=(articlecategoryid eq 1), it gives me the results, but when using ?$filter=(articlecategory eq :articlecategoryID), it fails and gives the error even though in the debugger it is passing the variable in correctly and setting the rest call as ?$filter=(articlecategoryid eq 1).

Comment: Hm, here's the [angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$resource/badcfg) on it. Are you sure you're not getting the error somewhere else? Also, I have an APP that makes CORS requests and I had to add this line `delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["X-Requested-With"]; // remove X-Requested-With`

Comment: Also, try commenting the      `$httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Content-Type'] = 'Application/json';` maybe that's buggy. Let me know how it works

Comment: My other calls of the same code, but different rest urls work without issue, so I am guessing I am not setting the parameter correctly. Is articlecategoryid eq :articlecategoryid correct I wonder.

Comment: Oh I think that's the issue, I don't think it's URL encoded. Try using [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) in your URL definition(at `return $resource('https://myrestcall.net/tables/articles/?$filter(articlecategoryid eq :articlecategoryID)'`

Comment: Great suggestion but it did not work. How have you filtered? I have found plenty of resources that illustrate using the ID, but not any other parts of a JSON call (i.e. articlecategoryID)

Comment: Does it at least do the request? Can you check the Network tab in your Dev tools?

Comment: It does and displays it perfectly as articlecategoryid eq 1 if I clicked on a link that passes the routeparam as 1. I also hard coded the REST call to be articlecategoryid eq 1 and it works so this is where I am confused since it resolved the correct url using the routeparam. I guess a larger question is what is the correct format for a REST call when I want to have a dynamic filter.