# Set $routeparam as a variable for filtering REST output

Tags: angularjs, rest

It is possible to set a routeparam as a variable to use in a filter? I don't believe I have the correct format. I am passing it along the URL, but can't seem to consume it properly. I need this working, because I can't seem to get the core REST call filtering as stated here: [Filter AngularJS REST JSON Data: error:badcfg Response does not match configured parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27788801/filter-angularjs-rest-json-data-errorbadcfg-response-does-not-match-configured)

Example:

Controller:

```
pfcControllers.controller('pfcCategoriesCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', 'pfcArticleCategories', function ($scope, $routeParams, pfcArticleCategories) {
    $scope.category = pfcArticleCategories.query();
    $scope.articlecategoryID = { articlecategoryID: $routeParams.articlecategoryID };
}]);
```

Filter:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Category ID</th>
            <th>Link</th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="articles in category | filter:{articlecategoryid:'articlecategoryID'} | orderBy:articleSortOrder">
            <td>{{articles.id}}</td>
            <td>{{articles.articletitle}}</td>
            <td>{{articles.articlecategoryid}}</td>
            <td><a ng-href="#article/{{article.id}}/{{article.articletitle}}">{{article.articletitle}}</a></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Link from another page:

```
<a ng-href="#categories/1">Category 1</a>
```

App.JS route:

```
when('/categories/:articlecategoryID', { templateUrl: './views/categories.html', controller: 'pfcCategoriesCtrl' }).
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this may work.

```
pfcControllers.controller('pfcCategoriesCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', 'pfcArticleCategories', function ($scope, $routeParams, pfcArticleCategories) {
    $scope.category = pfcArticleCategories.query();
    $scope.articlecategoryID = $routeParams.articlecategoryID;
}]);
```

Remove the quotes around articlecategoryID

```
<tr ng-repeat="articles in category | filter:{ articlecategoryid: articlecategoryID } | orderBy:articleSortOrder">
```

Comment: No such luck. If I hard code it, (ex. articlecategoryid: 1) it works, but it doesn't seem to respect the routeparam